# Where to add Multi language icons in application bundle for app approval submission - iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

could anyone here please let me know where to add icons files in a bundle for a multi language iphone application with each language having its translated icons?

The routine mentioned in the below link shows addition of one language  icon files to the Resources folder of the application bundle but does not cover multi language icons addition. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html.

Thanks

Great, i deleted the previous Icon.png reference from the Resources folder of the project and then added all the images the way you mentioned above. The project builds and run fine but the Icon does not appear on my test iPhone4 device. Below are the current setting of info.plist.

(Information Property List) ----------- Values

Icon file

Icon files

Item 0 ------------------------------------- Icon.png

Item 1 ------------------------------------- Icon@2x.png

Resource folder Files

Icon.png directory containing all the Icon images E.g. English, French

Icon@2x.png directory  containing all the Icon images E.g. English, French

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

B.T.W: I am new to this forum otherwise i would have posted the snapshots of Resources folder and info.plist to give you a clear picture.

Comment: Don't edit answers to reply to them; edit or leave a comment on your own question instead (and if/when you hit 50 rep you can leave comments on the answers as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the lproj directories in your main bundle and put your icons in there.

In your project directory create "en.lproj" and "fr.lproj" directories, the in each copy the corespondent Icon.png and Icon@2x.png (the english versions in en directory and the french version in fr directory).

The go to en.lproj directory and drag and drop the icons in to the navigation project (make sure that the copy option is disabled), then go to fr.lproj and to the same operation.

There you go build and run and make the test.